# Find the sum of the first $3n$ terms of a geometric series given the sum of the first $n$ terms is $48$ and the sum of first $2n$ terms is $60$

Tags: geometric-progressions

In a certain geometric series, the sum of the first $n$ terms is $48$ and the sum of the first $2n$ terms is $60$. Find the sum of the first $3n$ terms.

$$48= a_1\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

What do I do after this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: The sum of the first 3n terms is **63**. Now please follow @N.F.Taussig's suggestions.

Comment: Sorry. Yeah. :) The editing is done.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Define the sequence $(S_k)$ as follows: $S_1 = $ the sum of the first $n$ terms, $S_2 =$ the sum of terms $n+1$ to $2n$, and in general $S_r =$ the sum of terms $(r-1)n+1$ to $rn$.

Then $S_1,S_2,\ldots$ is a geometric progression (you should check this for yourself), with $S_1=48,S_2=12$. It is now immediate that $S_3=3$.

Answer (score 2):

The general expression for the sum of the  $n$ first terms of a geometric series is:

$$S_n=a_1{1-q^n\over 1-q}$$

So dividing $S_{2n}$ by $S_n$ one gets:

$${1-q^{2n}\over 1-q^n}={5\over 4}$$

And this is rearranged as $4q^{2n}-5q^n+1=0$. The trivial root $q^n=1$ is to be eliminated and we are left with $q^n=1/4$. We then rewrite the summation formula as ${a_1\over 1-q}={S_n\over 1-q^n}={4\over 3}\cdot 48=64$. So we have

$$S_{3n}=a_1{1-\left(q^n\right)^3\over 1-q}=64\cdot\left(1-{1\over 64}\right)=63$$

Comment: You meant $$\frac{1 - q^{2n}}{1 - q^{\color{red}{n}}} = \frac{5}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be first term of the geometric series. $r$ be the common ratio.

We know that for a geometric series, $S_n=\frac {a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$.Where $S_n$ is the sum of first $n$ terms.

So, we have given $S_n=48$ and $S_{2n}=60$. Let $S_{3n}=x$.

Now, $\frac {S_n}{S_{2n}}=\frac {48}{60}=\frac {1-r^n}{1-r^{2n}}$.

Solving this we get $r^n=\frac 14$.$ \Rightarrow$ $r^{2n}=\frac {1}{16}$ and $r^{3n}=\frac {1}{64}$. (Note: $r^n=1$ is also a root. but we discard it since if it happens, then $S_n=0$ which is a contradiction to the given $S_n=48$).

Now $\frac {S_{2n}}{S_{3n}}=\frac {60}{x}=\frac {1-r^{2n}}{1-r^{3n}}$.

Putting values of $r^{2n}$ and $r^{3n}$, we get $x=63$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=48;$$
$$a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots+a_{2n}=12;$$
$$\frac{a_{2n+1}+a_{2n+2}+\cdots+a_{3n}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots+a_{2n}}=\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+_\cdots+a_{2n}}{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}=\frac14=r^n,$$
where $r=\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ is the common ratio of the geometric progression; so
$$a_{2n+1}+a_{2n+2}+\cdots+a_{3n}=3$$
and
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{3n}=48+12+3=63.$$